# Это интересно(,) играть с котом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли в этом предложении запятая?

■ Это интересно(,) играть с котом.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Следует поставить тире: *Это **интересно — играть** с котом.*
Меняем местами подлежащее и сказуемое, получаем:
***Играть** с котом — это **интересно.***
Ср.: *Играть с котом интересно.* (Но даже в этом случае постановка тире перед сказуемым «интересно» не будет ошибкой, если предполагается пауза.)

> **5.** При наличии паузы между главными членами предложения **тире** ставится между подлежащим, выраженным неопределенной формой глагола, и сказуемым, выраженным предикативным наречием на ***-о*** (категорией состояния): ***Уступить — позорно*** (Тендр.); *Это очень **несносно — переезжать*** (Гонч.); *Это **ужасно — струсить** в последний момент; Это чертовски **весело — кататься** на лодке* [ср. без паузы: ***Кататься** на лодке **весело**; **Судить** человека в немилости очень **легко*** (Л. Т.)].

Источник: [Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91) (справочник Розенталя).